# Caught Exception while trying to serialize

Tags: java, serialization

I've the following error in my logs

```
[6/6/11 17:16:33:558 CEST] 00000005 WASSession    E MTMBuffWrapper storeObject SESN0200E: Caught Exception while trying to serialize.
[6/6/11 17:16:33:558 CEST] 00000005 WASSession    E MTMHashMap handlePropertyHits SESN0202E: Failed to replicate attribute changeBankStatusForm
```

I've identified the object which raise this error, this object is huge, a lot of attribute containing them self attributes

How can I identify the exact attribute which raise the serialization error

Thanks

Comment: more from your stacktrace may help us

Comment: the complete error is in the question now (only 2 lines)

Comment: that looks like WebSphere. This is what I hate about app servers.

Answer (score 2):

**Update** it appears that your application server is handling the exception wrongly, so you'd have to manually look through all fields and check if their types implement `Serializable`

---

You are most likely handling your exception wrong. I assume you are doing:

```
try { ..
} catch(Exception ex) {
   System.out.println("Caught Exception while trying to serialize"); // wrong
   ex.printStackTrace(); // better
   logger.error("Serialization problem", ex); //best
}
```

If that's the case - you can't get any more info, because you've swallowed the exception. You should call `ex.printStackTrace()` instead (or use a logging framework)

Then the exception will tell you which class fails the serialization, and so you will be able to mark it as `Serializable`

Comment: thanks for your answer, manually look through all fields will takes a lot of time, I was hoping for an automated way to do that.